# Smalltalk Parser

Tags: parsing, smalltalk

I am new to SmallTalk, I am using VisualWorks. I need to parse a string and insert each char into an array excluding white space and all the punctuation marks. This is not a homework assignment but a part of a big project and I can't seem to figure it out.
Please help!

Comment: Can you post what you have already tried? Can you post more details about exactly what you need to do? Right now, your question is fairly vague; it's hard to tell exactly what you need to do, or where you are stuck.

Comment: unparsed
 
 ^unparsed isNil
  ifTrue:
   [unparsed := String new asValue]
  ifFalse:
   [unparsed] that is all i have, i need to store all the chars in an array.

Comment: @AndriyLysak Please look at your comment. It is not a place to post code. Please put it in your question with a full explanation of what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be as simple as this (I used VSE, but VW shouldn't be much different):

```
toThrowAway := #($  $. $, $: $; $! $?). "this contains all the characters that you want to throw away. Simply add anything else you don't want in the result"
(anArray := unparsed reject:[:c| toThrowAway includes: c]) asArray.
```

EDIT (after your comment):

As I wrote, I'm not using Visual Works, maybe it's just a different implementation of asString. Is that what you see when you inspect the resulting array or when you display it on a workspace? What's the size of the resulting Array? Anyway you can try it in a  more explicit way:

```
toThrowAway := #($  $. $, $: $; $! $?). "this contains all the characters that you want to throw away. Simply add anything else you don't want in the result"
parsedString := unparsed reject:[:c| toThrowAway includes: c]).
anArray := Array new: parsedString size.
1 to: parsedString size do: [:i| anArray at: i put: (parsedString at:i)].
```

Comment: this seems to work but i get this as a result:#($t "16r0074" $h "16r0068" $i "16r0069" $s "16r0073" $i "16r0069" $s "16r0073" $a "16r0061" $s "16r0073" $t "16r0074" $r "16r0072" $i "16r0069" $n "16r006E" $g "16r0067") how do i remove the "16rXXXX" from the array?

Comment: the size was 13 i figure it out, thanx for the help!

Answer (score 2):

For larger assignments/more complex problems, take a look at PetitParser and/or SmaCC (both on the public store). PetitParser documentation is on Lukas Renggli's website.

Some issues you might run into:

- are you sure you need an Array, not a String as result?
- what encoding do you have and need: 8-bit characters (which codepage)/UTF-8/UTF-16?
- if you need to do this a lot, there are much better algorithms, using e.g. table lookup. The accepted answer gets slower as the number of rejected characters increases

Answer (score 1):

Parsing is usually done using Streams to source input from. Create a stream out of your string and enumerate using

```
[stream atEnd] whileFalse: [
   char := stream next.
   ...
].
```

This way you can operate on large input sets, e.g. from a file or a socket, and keep your memory consumption fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Without thinking about the factors of encoding, here is a simple code segment. The key is that you using an OrderedCollection to gather all the alphabetic characters then converting it into an Array(or other collection you need).

```
|aString aCol|
aString := 'abc def  $%^    g()h!'.
aCol := OrderedCollection new.
aString do:[:c|
    c isAlphabetic ifTrue:[
        aCol add:c
    ]

].
^aCol asArray
```